# PowerShell Add-ADManager group script

Tags: powershell

I have developed three PowerShell scripts that allow me to automatically add and remove users from a security group via the contents of an OU or OUs. Due to auditing needs, these scripts will require a log file. I am in need of assistance with creating a log file that says what was added and or removed from the group (variable: `$SGshadowUG`). You can find the script I'm using below.

I've attempted to use `try`/`catch`/`finally` to no avial.

```bsh
$OUusers     = "OU=Users,OU=organizationalUnit,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com"
$OUdallas    = "OU=Dallas,OU=Users,OU=organizationalUnit,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com"
$OUremote    = "OU=Remote Users,OU=Users,OU=organizationalUnit,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com"
$OUmemphis   = "OU=Memphis,OU=Users,OU=organizationalUnit,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com"
$OUonprocess = "OU=OnProcess,OU=Users,OU=organizationalUnit,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com"
$SGshadowUG  = "CN=shadow-Standard-Users,OU=Groups,OU=organizationalUnit,DC=internal,DC=domain,DC=com"

Get-ADGroupMember –Identity $SGshadowUG | Where-Object {
    ($_.distinguishedName -match $OUremote) -and
    ($_.distinguishedName -match $OUdallas) -and
    ($_.distinguishedName -match $OUmemphis) -and
    ($_.distinguishedName -notmatch $OUonprocess)
} | ForEach-Object {
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership –Identity $_ –MemberOf $SGshadowUG –Confirm:$false
}
Get-ADUser –SearchBase $OUdallas –SearchScope OneLevel –LDAPFilter "(!memberOf=$SGshadowUG)" |
    ForEach-Object {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership –Identity $_ –MemberOf $SGshadowUG}
Get-ADUser –SearchBase $OUmemphis –SearchScope OneLevel –LDAPFilter "(!memberOf=$SGshadowUG)" |
    ForEach-Object {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership –Identity $_ –MemberOf $SGshadowUG}
Get-ADUser –SearchBase $OUremote –SearchScope OneLevel –LDAPFilter "(!memberOf=$SGshadowUG)" |
    ForEach-Object {Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership –Identity $_ –MemberOf $SGshadowUG}
```

Comment: Just send your screen out to a file, using the normal file managing cmdlets.

Comment: I don't see any `try`/`catch` in your script. You'd use it like this: `try {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership ...; "$_ removed from $SGshadowUG" | Add-Content 'your.log'} catch {"error removing $_ from $SGshadowUG" | Add-Content 'your.log'}`.

Comment: Please explain your "auditing needs" - if you need to be able to monitor or investigate and/or explain query-level behavior, then you should probably just turn on DS Access Audit logging on your Domain Controllers and collect those logs - then you won't need to worry about _any_ script modifying AD

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen

My audit essentially needs to show when a user was added and or removed from with a date and time stamp appended.

Comment: @Brandon yeah, that's definitely the kind of things you want the Domain Controller to log, rather than relying on the script/client - what's stopping anyone from adding or removing users using another script (or tool) without any logging built in? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I agree with that, but I want to limit access to servers. The support staff will use the information from the logs to determine if there is an issue.

Comment: You could have audit events forwarded to a central log server.

Answer (score 0):

What have you search for?
What have you tried?

This is a real common PowerShell 101 kind of thing, and lots of ways to do it. You just have to decide how much time / effort you'd want to put into it and of course what will work best long term for all involved.

Just send your screen output to a file, using the normal file managing cmdlets...

Example:

```
Out-File
```

Or
    Start-Transcript # logs everything the script is doing.

...etc.

You can even leverage verbosity in the use case and discussed an shown here:

> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-write-verbose-output

You can even write to existing event logs or create your own and write to that, as discussed and shown here:

> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-to-use-powershell-to-write-to-event-logs

Or leveraging examples via a simple search:

'create PowerShell log file for you script'

> How to Log Scripts in PowerShell
>   https://key2consulting.com/how-to-log-scripts-in-powershell

```
#Function that logs a message to a text file
function LogMessage
{
    param([string]$Message, [string]$LogFile)

    ((Get-Date).ToString() + " - " + $Message) >> $LogFile;
}

#Function that deletes log file if it exists
function DeleteLogFile
{
    param([string]$LogFile)

    #Delete log file if it exists
    if(Test-Path $LogFile)
    {
        Remove-Item $LogFile
    }
}
```

> How to Build a Logging Function in PowerShell
>   https://blog.ipswitch.com/how-to-build-a-logging-function-in-powershell

```
function Write-Log 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Message,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateSet('Information','Warning','Error')]
        [string]$Severity = 'Information'
    )

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Time = (Get-Date -f g)
        Message = $Message
        Severity = $Severity
    } | Export-Csv -Path "$env:Temp\LogFile.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Or this one

> PowerShell: How to easily create log files for your scripts
>   https://9to5it.com/powershell-logging-function-library

There are full modules to leverage from the MS powershellgallery.com

```
Find-Module -Name '*log*' | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Even prebuilt scripts for script logging use case

> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-Log-A-Simple-Logging-52827c98
>   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-Log-PowerShell-999c32d0